# How to get the facebook page data using facebook's graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the facebook page data using the following link:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page/bachicheckkar
```

And it returns the following:

```
{
 "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /bachicheckkar",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why doesn't it fetch the page data? I'm sorry but I'm a newbie here.

Comment: Was the answer helpful? You can mark it accepted if it was helpful and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to access data in a wrong way! I'll suggest you to go through the [Graph API Page Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) since you're a Newbie.

The way it's done is you simply have to make a request using this simple link:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/bachicheckkar
```

However, in your case, it says the page doesn't exists! You can try it using your page's Id. It's working fine for other pages though. For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/seewaymore
```

Comment: how to find page id of a public page?